# storyboard refresh issue Xcode

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard, constraints, xcode9.3

I have an issue of storyboard refresh all views, when I change constraints it cannot be change in storyboard but change in simulator and device.
But when I reopen my project then it refresh.I tried below step but nothing happened
Select storyboard->editor-> refresh all views
and also automatically refresh already checked.
Is this bug of Xcode 9.3?

Here I attach image:-
[image]

but in simulator look like perfect below image:-

[image]

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer it's happened due to IBDesignable in my custom library class.If I remove all IBDesignable it's work fine.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have also gone through this strange issue. I believe it creates if your project becomes so much heavy and lot of storyboards used. Therefore using Xib instead of Storyboard is the good option.

If you restart xcode and reopen your project then you can see your view as expected with updated constraint.